# How one approaches designing a view with MVVM best practices in mind

Tags: wpf, mvvm

This question is about how to factor the app design with MVVM in mind. I understand the general concepts of MVVM (ViewModel is not aware of the View, Models represent domain objects, etc...). I'm also aware of Commands and how some controls can invoke commands on the ViewModel.

What I can't figure out is how to factor a real-life app to fit this model (as opposed to simple textbox/button/query database examples). Here are some questions:

- In a main view I have preview section that displays contextual data depending on what the user is doing (i.e. by interacting with certain controls, show some preview section). Should the View contain all the possible previews in XAML and then show/hide/update? Should ViewModel have properties like "public bool ShowPreviewA" and "public bool ShowPreviewB" set by ViewModel's internal state machine?
- Where should the logic live when some controls have intricate interactions between them. For example, 3 checkboxes where at least one must be selected, by preventing unchecking. Seems to me that it would pollute the ViewModel on one hand, and also feel like there is certain "knowledge" about the View on the other hand.

This question is difficult to articulate properly (if I could, I would probably understand MVVM much better).

Any tips are welcomed.

**EDIT**:
The real question is how to break down the problem when writing the functionality of ViewModels. Is it a combination of top-down - i.e. encode every possible View state in ViewModel properties - and bottom-up - i.e. each logically related set of controls receive their properties from child ViewModels that report "up" some logical state (e.g. valid input)?

Comment: Can you dynamically load the various viewmodels?

Comment: I'm sure I _can_... but can you explain what it solves - I miss your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a main view I have preview section that displays contextual data
>   depending on what the user is doing (i.e. by interacting with certain
>   controls, show some preview section). Should the View contain all the
>   possible previews in XAML and then show/hide/update? Should ViewModel
>   have properties like "public bool ShowPreviewA" and "public bool
>   ShowPreviewB" set by ViewModel's internal state machine?

No, of course not, if these "previews" are completely different UIs with completely different data, then use `DataTemplates`.

For example:

Given some classes:

```
public class Person: BusinessEntity //BusinessEntity is just a fictional base class for Model classes
{
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}

public class Product: BusinessEntity
{
    public string ProductName {get;set;
}
```

suppose your ViewModel is defined like this:

```
public class SomeViewModel: ViewModelBase //Same comment as above
{
    public BusinessEntity SelectedEntity {get;set;} //NotifyPropertyChanged() etc
}
```

Your XAML can be defined like this:

```
<Window ...>
   <Window.Resources>

       <!-- DataTemplate for Person class -->
       <DataTemplate DataType="Person">
           <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
       </DataTemplate>

       <!-- DataTemplate for Product class -->
       <DataTemplate DataType="Product">
           <TextBox Text="{Binding ProductName}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </Window.Resources>

   <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedEntity}"/>

</Window>
```

WPF will take care of rendering the appropiate `DataTemplate` inside the `ContentPresenter` depending on which object type is put in the `SelectedEntity` property in the ViewModel.

---

> Where should the logic live when some controls have intricate
>   interactions between them. For example, 3 checkboxes where at least
>   one must be selected, by preventing unchecking. Seems to me that it
>   would pollute the ViewModel on one hand, and also feel like there is
>   certain "knowledge" about the View on the other hand.

You can easily inherit `ObservableCollection<T>` to create this logic in a reusable manner. Then in your ViewModel just put some `public SelectableCollection<T> MyItems {get;set;}` where the selection / mutual exclusion, etc is handled by `SelectableCollection` and so on.

Bottom line: MVVM is all about reusability and encapsulation of functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Can I create conditional (as in programmatically assigned, or depending on the type of bound object) DataTemplate?

Comment: This SelectableCollection - is this like a nested ViewModel?

Comment: Ah... I think I got the SelectableCollection idea.

Comment: I understand now what you mean by DataTemplates.